# Configure a DNS-server for a domain

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind

In Ubuntu I'm trying to configure a DNS-server for a domain. I haven't tested it yet because I haven't got access to the virtual box yet. But I can feel that it contains problems. Can someone spot any obvious errors? I know it's hard without running a server test.

I have configured named.conf.local like this:

```
zone "craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se" {
type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se";
};
```

Now I'm trying to configure the zone file but I'm sort of confused what to change the localhost to for it to be able to connect.

I also want to add the following hosts:

- ns1 (with a NS- and a A-record for the DNS-server)
- www
- ftp
- 'student name' (this should be the name for the virtual server)

This is what I have changed so far:

```
;
; BIND data file for example.com
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se. root.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
    IN      A       192.168.1.10
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se.
@       IN      A       craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se
www     IN      A       www.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se
ftp     IN      A       ftp.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se
```

Comment: A records need an IP address, not another name. So you can't do `@ IN A craig.example.com.` but you can do `@ IN A 10.10.10.10`.

Comment: You have all sorts of issues. `named-checkzone example.com /path/to/zonefile` will check zone file syntax and tell you what is wrong.  Or be lazy and use a zone file generator like http://www.zonefile.org

Answer (score 0):

Like the other person said A records require addresses. But you can use CNAMEs like I think you are trying in your example .

```
wwww   IN   A      192.168.1.10 
ftp    IN   CNAME  wwww
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I have edited the configs after reading your comments. Does this look more OK?

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    5D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se. 
root.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se. (
                 2018052100         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                      10800 ); Negative Cache TTL
;
                IN      NS      ns1.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se.

ns1             IN      A       xxx.239.163.100
www             IN      A       xxx.239.163.110
ftp             IN      A       xxx.239.163.120
craig           IN      A       xxx.239.163.130
```

And this is what the named.conf.local looks like:

```
zone    "craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se" in {
    allow-transfers { any; };
    file "/etc/bind/db.craig.linuxcourse.tfe.ltu.se";
    type master;
};
```

Comment: the line starting with ns1 should be ns1 IN A and not NS; we also nowadays use as somewhat de facto standard a Serial of YYMMDDnn as in 2018052100 for the first edit of the day. The max value allowed for the negative cache in SOA is 10800